# fwrite, writes multiple times using "a"

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm doing some testing as I'm new to PHP and Wordpress.

On refresh the following code runs
**functions.php**

```
<?php

$content = "some text here\n";
$fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/wp-content/themes/zerif-lite-child/myText.txt","a");
fwrite($fp,$content);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Which writes to the .txt file multiple times!
If I use "wb" it will write to the file only once, but I want this code to append the file, not overwrite it everytime.

I've tried using flock() but that produces the same result.

Why is it writing to this file multiple times when I append it?

Comment: Perhaps because you're calling it 9 times?

Comment: And that you could test e.g. by adding a random value to your content: `$content = "some text here\n";
$content = mt_rand() . '|' . $content;`

Comment: Where am I calling it multiple times @MarkBaker ?

Comment: I tried that @VolkerK and I get 9 different numbers with my message at the end of each. So it seems to be running 9 times in that instance!
Why is this doing it? using "wb" seems to only run once! but using "a" makes it run multiple times

Comment: @user3838036 I don't know.... you're not showing anything more than the code that you're executing.... you're not showing how you're executing it, or where you're executing it

Comment: "but using "a" makes it run multiple times" - very unlikely. You just didn't notice while using " wb" because the contents of the file had been ovewritten.

Comment: @MarkBaker I'm using a fresh Wordpress install with a theme and child theme.
So in my child theme folder I only have 3 files, functions.php, style.css and myText.txt.
Wordpress must run it multiple times as part of the refresh process?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the issue resulted from how parameters were passed to the php page and a 3rd party piece of software on my computer. I discovered that when using GET multiple lines would be written in the file however POST worked fine. After examining my Apache access log I observed that when using query strings and GET the php was getting called more than once and from different agents. After taking a closer look at my computer I realized that a program I had for working with streams was attempting to capture data on the query string. After removing that software everything worked fine.

Comment: It appears this was only partially correct. The problem was encountered again and appears to involve how parameters are passed to the page. If passed as GET I get multiple lines written. If I pass as POST I only get one line.

Comment: Ignore my above comment. I had put that in response to my previous answer which i have since edited.